# horizontal line css problem with ie 9 , <hr /> color style not work in ie 9

Tags: html, colors, internet-explorer-9, horizontal-line

why the below html code does not work in ie 9:

```
<hr style="color:red;"/>
```

how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this...

```
<hr style="background: red; border: none; height: 5px;" />
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/TBpYP/).